# Union of Data.Map.fromList could not match type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and trying to create a game board of the game Reversi (Othello). Thereafter, I want to use this to return a starting Player and the initial starting position of the board. So two issues.

1. Generate game plan

I have two data types for the different Players and possible moves to make.

```
data Player = Black | White
  deriving (Eq,Show)

{- Game moves.
   Pass represents a passing move. Move i represents a move to field i.
   INVARIANT: 0 <= i <= 63 in Move i
 -}
data Move = Pass | Move Int
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

My initial idea was to create an Associated list (dictionary) where each key value pair makes up a field on the board. So the key would be (0...63) and the values could be Black/White or empty. However, the Player data type cannot be modified to include e.g, Empty.

To play the game, I need to create a function that returns which player that starts and the initial board. The starting position should look like this:

[image: Start position]

So I was thinking I could use Haskell's built in Data.Map to create an empty board and then create the initial position and then union these two to obtain a complete game board with the starting position.

```
fields :: [Integer]
fields = [x | x <- [1 .. 63]]

type Field = Maybe Player

emptyBoard :: Data.Map.Map Integer (Maybe a)
emptyBoard = Data.Map.fromList (zip fields (repeat Nothing))

startBoard =
  Data.Map.fromList
    [ (27, White),
      (36, White),
      (28, Black),
      (35, Black)
    ]

initialBoard = Data.Map.union startBoard emptyBoard
```

Following this way of thinking about the board:

[image]

However, when running this in the Prelude, I get:

```
<interactive>:42:45: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Maybe a0' with `Player'
      Expected type: Data.Map.Internal.Map k Player
        Actual type: Data.Map.Internal.Map k (Maybe a0)
    * In the second argument of `Data.Map.Internal.union', namely
        `emptyBoard'
      In the expression: Data.Map.Internal.union startBoard emptyBoard
      In an equation for `initialBoard':
          initialBoard = Data.Map.Internal.union startBoard emptyBoard
```

How can I go about creating an emptyBoard with the same type as in startBoard?

2. Initial position

My second issue is to create a state of the game. So, something like this.

```
-- Board consists of tuples with integers and Player or empty
data Board = Board [(Integer, Field)]
-- type State = () is required to be a type synonym 
type State = (Player, Board)
```

So that when creating my function to generate the initial game, with something like this:

```
initial :: Player -> State
initial p = if p == Black then (Black, initialBoard) else (White, initialBoard)
```

The type declaration of initial cannot be changed. Nevertheless, I get a warning from the intellisense:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Board’
              with actual type ‘Data.Map.Map k0 Player’
• In the expression: initialBoard
```

So, in summary. 1) how can I generate a startBoard with only the middle fields populated and the rest empty and 2), the initial game plan with a player and the boards starting position.

Comment: Your `startBoard` is a `Map Integer Player`, not `Map Integer (Maybe Player)`.

Comment: It is however not clear to me why the `Map` should store the values for empty squares. Why not just use the `startBoard`? Every grid that is not in the map, is then simply empty.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Possible just to add new values as the game goes on to the dictionary.  Any suggestion on how to make this a data type that can be updated i.e., return a new "State" after each move? So that the Player that is about to move is returned and the state of the board when that move is about to happen, e.g.: type State = (Player, Board)

Comment: you can use `insert` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:insert and `delete` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:delete to insert values and delete keys from the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I generate a startBoard with only the middle fields populated and the rest empty

The `startBoard` you wrote works perfectly for that. Don't overthink things. Throw away `emptyBoard` and `initialBoard` entirely. Representing empty squares by simply not having that key in the `Map` is going to be simpler than having an explicit key that maps to `Nothing` anyway.

> how can I generate the initial game plan with a player and the boards starting position

Ya just tuple 'em up.

```
type State = (Player, Map Integer Player)

initial :: Player -> State
initial p = (p, startBoard)
```